# python chan.send command 1064

Tags: python, mysql, sql, paramiko

i have this error when i`m executing a chan.send command :

[image: error1]

this is my script:

```
chan.send("mysql --user='test' --password=mypw --database='bugs_mogis' --execute='select login_name, realname, last_seen_date from profiles where disabledtext = "";'")
    chan.send('\n')
    time.sleep(1)
    resp = chan.recv(9999)
    output = resp.decode('ascii').split(',')
    print (''.join(output))

    chan.close()
```

It`s strange cause in "putty" this command works but also i have this error
[image: error2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a problem with quotation marks in your SQL string.

```py
"mysql --user='test' --password=mypw --database='bugs_mogis' --execute='select login_name, realname, last_seen_date from profiles where disabledtext = "";'"
```

In the last part you enclose `;` in `"`, however your whole string starts and ends with `"`, so python understands it as ending one string and starting another, and then joining them together. This is how python sees your string: (check the difference at the end)

```py
"mysql --user='test' --password=mypw --database='bugs_mogis' --execute='select login_name, realname, last_seen_date from profiles where disabledtext = ;'"
```

This way SQL doesn't like the `where disabledtext = ;` part. To make it work, instead of enclosing whole string in `"`, use `"""` (see [multiline strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0295/)):

```py
""" mysql --user='test' --password=mypw --database='bugs_mogis' --execute='select login_name, realname, last_seen_date from profiles where disabledtext = "";' """
```